# Auto create html pages from Database in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

I'm hoping someone can direct me in the right direction. I've been struggling to find information or what to be looking for, I'm new to rails and looking to use mySQL data to create the controllers and views for new webpages automatically.

For instance if I have a mySQL table called `Players` as follows

```
NAME     |     PHOTO        |    AGE    |    COUNTRY    

Player1  |  ../image1.png   |    20     |   USA     
Player2  |  ../image2.png   |    30     |   UK  
Player3  |  ../image3.png   |    40     |   RUS
```

When this table is updated, I would like to have the controller and views for html page `domain.tld/"NAME"` automatically created, i.e. `domain.tld/player1` or `domain.tld/player2`, etc...

The html/View file should be created from a template which would then include the other information in the table like below

```
<%= image_tag("PHOTO") %>  
<ul>
<li>"AGE"</li>
<li>"COUNTRY"</li>
</ul>
```

Example

```
<%= image_tag("../image1.png") %>
<ul>
<li>20</li>
<li>USA</li>
</ul>
```

If anyone is able to help me out with how it would work or what the script should look like, or where to find more information id appreciate that greatly.

Comment: you ought to go through a tutorial throughly as to solve this you really need to understand several moving parts and how they interact, I'd suggest this here: https://www.railstutorial.org/book - currently this question is likely to get closed for being too broad

Comment: Thank you, I have gone through some basic rails guides which covered more my design of the site. but have not seen anything about any sort of methods that will auto generate the pages and as you say see how to combine the moving parts between sql/rails/javascirpt etc..  i will say the reading tutourials often confuse me.. find it a lot easier when i see whats happening on the more practical side to get to grips opposed to reading theory. But Hopefully any more info will help on which direction i need to look like cron jobs, or javascript, any rails methods etc.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for just a simple PlayerView and PlayerController. You can look into Marionette and the free book for it will guide you through what you need.

Comment: Thank you Frenchie for the suggestions, I'll have a look into them and see if it will suit what i need, are you referring to marionette.js?

Comment: @user2897821 the tutorial linked is a fully developed example of some complexity rather than just reams of theory (I know what you mean about that, interesting, but not the same as a working example) - you'll cover everything you need to know to answer the question